# MailKit write HtmlBody to the database in string

Tags: c, asp.net-core, mailkit

Model

```
 public class Mail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Tema { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Client IMAP

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            var Emails = _context.Settings.FirstOrDefault();
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
            client.Connect(Emails.Imap,Convert.ToInt32(Emails.ImapPort), true);
            client.Authenticate(Emails.Login, Emails.Password);
            client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            var inbox = client.Inbox;
            var messages = inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);
            if (messages.Where(c => c.Flags.Value.HasFlag(MessageFlags.Seen) != true).Count() > 0)
            {

                foreach (var message in messages.Where(c => c.Flags.Value.HasFlag(MessageFlags.Seen) != true))
                {
                    var mime = inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
                    Mail mail = new Mail();
                    mail.Date = DateTime.Now;
                    mail.Note = Convert.ToString(mime);
                    mail.Tema = message.Envelope.Subject.ToString();
                    mail.Email = Convert.ToString(message.Date);
                    _context.Add(mail);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    break;
                }
            }
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
```

as a result, I get an unreadable string in the Note

```
   Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

 PGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50
 PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7Ij48dGl0bGU+0JzQldCU0JjQkNCb0J7Qk9CY0K88L3RpdGxlPjxz
 dHlsZT4uYmR7Zm9udDogMTI1JS8xMTUlIGFyaWFsLCBzYW5zLXNlcmlmOyBjb2xvcjog
 IzAwM0U1MDsgbWFyZ2luLXRvcDogMTJweH0gcHtmb250OiAxMDAlIGFyaWFsLCBzYW5z
 LXNlcmlmOyBjb2xvcjogIzAwM0U1MDsgbWFyZ2luLXRvcDogMTJweH0gdGR7Zm9udDog
 ODAlLzExNSUgYXJpYWwsIHNhbnMtc2VyaWY7IGNvbG9yOiAjMDAzRTUwOyBtYXJnaW4t
 dG9wOiAxMnB4fSB0ZC5oZHJ7Zm9udDogYm9sZCAxMXB4LzE0cHggYXJpYWwsIHNhbnMt
 c2VyaWY7IGNvbG9yOiAjMWIxYjU2OyBtYXJnaW4tdG9wOiAxMnB4OyBsaW5lLWhlaWdo
 dDoxNXB4O30gLnNlYXJjaF9obHtjb2xvcjogI2ZmZmZmZjtiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9y
 OiAjMDAzODQ4O308L3N0eWxlPjwvaGVhZD48Ym9keSBiZ2NvbG9yPSNGRkZGRkY+PHRh
 ......
```

after "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" we see the html file in bass64.  Is there any way MileKit will record only the file data itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially calling `MimePart.ToString()`... and, well, as far as MimeKit knows, you want the MIME as a string.

But that's not what you actually want.

What you want is the actual text content.

Here's what you need to do in your loop:

```
var html = (TextPart) inbox.GetBodyPart (message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
Mail mail = new Mail();
mail.Date = DateTime.Now;
mail.Note = html.Text;
...
```

A `TextPart` is a subclass of `MimePart` that represents `text/*` MIME parts (including `text/html`) and has a few nice convenient API's that can be used to get (or set) the textual content of the `MimePart` as a string rather than having to deal with streams - most notably, the `.Text` property.

That should answer your question, but I'm not done because your code could use a few more changes.

Instead of asking MailKit to `Fetch()` the metadata for every single message in your inbox, why not request only what you need?

Since you clearly don't care about messages that have already been seen, you could take advantage of IMAP's SEARCH functionality, like so:

```
var uids = inbox.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen);
if (uids.Count > 0)
{
    var messages = inbox.Fetch (uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);
    foreach (var message in messages.Where (c => !c.Flags.Value.HasFlag (MessageFlags.Seen))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note: You still need to use the `Where()` filter because it's possible for message flags to change (by another client) between the `Search()` and the `Fetch()`. I also changed the `MessageSummaryItems` to be *only* the fields that you are actually using.

You can also get rid of your `if (messages.Where(c => c.Flags.Value.HasFlag(MessageFlags.Seen) != true).Count() > 0)` statement because it is redundant and requires a full pass at the returned data when the very next thing you do is to loop over the data anyway.

And since you `break;` out of the loop as soon as you find the very first message that hasn't been seen, why not do this instead?

```
var message = messages.FirstOrDefault (x => !x.Flags.Value.HasFlag (MessageFlags.Seen));
if (message != null)
{
    var html = (TextPart) inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
    Mail mail = new Mail();
    mail.Date = DateTime.Now;
    mail.Note = html.Text;
    mail.Tema = message.Envelope.Subject;
    mail.Email = Convert.ToString(message.Envelope.Date);
    _context.Add(mail);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The end result is:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient())
{
    var Emails = _context.Settings.FirstOrDefault();
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;
    client.Connect(Emails.Imap,Convert.ToInt32(Emails.ImapPort), true);
    client.Authenticate(Emails.Login, Emails.Password);
    client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

    var inbox = client.Inbox;
    var uids = inbox.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen);
    if (uids.Count > 0)
    {
        var messages = inbox.Fetch (uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);
        var message = messages.FirstOrDefault (x => !x.Flags.Value.HasFlag (MessageFlags.Seen));
        if (message != null)
        {
            var html = (TextPart) inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, message.HtmlBody);
            Mail mail = new Mail();
            mail.Date = DateTime.Now;
            mail.Note = html.Text;
            mail.Tema = message.Envelope.Subject;
            mail.Email = Convert.ToString(message.Envelope.Date);
            _context.Add(mail);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

The last change you'll need to make to the above code is what to do if the message doesn't *have* an HTML body. What if the message only has a `text/plain` body? Or what if it doesn't contain *any* `text/*` parts at all?

You'll need to figure out what you want to do when that happens...

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer, sorry for "break" it should not be there while I tried to insert it so as not to go through all the unread letters every time. And of course the flag will change after reading the letter. But your example will greatly simplify my code.